# Plus signs in Diablo 3 for ps4

Tags: diablo-iii-console

What do the plus signs mean in diablo 3? They are next to the sword and shield when looking at items in the inventory.

[image: diablo3]

Answer (score 1):

As @Frank suggested, it's your healing stat. Or more specifically, it's your Regen stat. This is how much health you will regenerate per second.

This can be boosted by equipment that has a "+ Regen" effect.

Comment: For anyone wondering why this is downvoted, view the revision history.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for an answer last weekend and found following answer on the [battlenet forums](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/13842144840):

> It means healing. Life per hit, Life after kill, Life per second, Health globe bonus. In the PC version the tooltip states something like 'the amount of health you potentially heal per second based on...'